# Simple object comparer

Tags: c#, reflection

Creating a simple object compare function for public system types in a class meaning only looking at the first level of a class no breaking into an object and comparing sub properties.

It performs very quickly however I am unsure about the extensibility of it for the future should criteria evolve

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Compare<T1, T2>(this T1 Object1, T2 Object2) where T1 : IComparer
{
    if (Object2 == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Parameter object not instantiated");

    Type TypeOfObject1 = typeof(T1);
    PropertyInfo[] Object1Properties = TypeOfObject1.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    Type TypeOfObject2 = typeof(T2);
    PropertyInfo[] Object2Properties = TypeOfObject2.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (Object1Properties.Count() == 0 || Object2Properties.Count() == 0)
        throw new NullReferenceException("No public properties found");

    var DifferencesFound = Object1Properties
        .Join(Object2Properties,
                Object1Property => Object1Property.Name,
                Object2Property => Object2Property.Name,
                (Object1Property, Object2Property) => new { Object1Property = Object1Property, Object2Property = Object2Property })

        .Where(x => ((Type.GetTypeCode(x.Object1Property.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object
                        && Type.GetTypeCode(x.Object2Property.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object
                    )
                    && !x.Object1Property.GetValue(Object1).Equals(x.Object2Property.GetValue(Object2)))
                )
        .Select(x => x.Object1Property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as string ?? x.Object1Property.Name)
        .AsEnumerable();

    return DifferencesFound;
}
```

Note: Reads `DisplayName` attribute if it is not found then uses name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the name, `Compare` doesn't explain what this method does (and I had to read all the code to have an idea). Don't be afraid of longer names like `GetMatchedPropertiesWithDifferentValues()` (or something like that...).

Maybe you have a reason for that, in code you're not showing, but there is no requirement for `T1` to implement `IComparer` (I'd guess `IComparable` but...`IComparer`?)

Names reloaded. Usually local variables (and parameters) are camelCase.

Both `Object1` and `Object2` can be `null`, check for both. You should never ever throw `NullReferenceException`, if a function argument is `null` and it should not then you have to throw `ArgumentNullException`.

This code:

> ```
> Type TypeOfObject1 = typeof(T1);
> PropertyInfo[] Object1Properties = TypeOfObject1.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
> ```

Can be simplified to:

```
var object1Properties = typeof(T1).GetProperties();
```

However if caller specifies the generic types like this (just an example...):

```
Compare<Base, Base>(new Derived(), new Derived());
```

You may get the wrong result (what do you expect here? To get properties of `Base` or of `Derived`?) Just be aware of this (and document it).

You call `Count()` on `PropertyInfo[]`. LINQ implementation is smart enough but it really has no sense to avoid using `Length` property. Again do not throw `NullReferenceException`. Is there any null object? No, just an object without public properties then you can throw `ArgumentException` (possibly specialized for the two parameters).

You may want to filter properties to feed `Join()` (what you're doing later in `Where()` clause) before the `Join()`. Also, move it to a separate `GetEligiblePropertiesForComparison()` method.

Only when `T1` and `T2` coincide (maybe a separate overload?): if you just get the intersection of the two lists you can skip creating the temporary objects.

Is there a reason you do not compare reference types? Checking `TypeCode` works pretty well but moving this check to a separate method is even better. Also consider `x.PropertyType.IsPrimitiveType || x.PropertyType == typeof(string)` (if it's what you meant, comparison of `DBNull` can be tricky).

You might want to move comparison to a separate method where you check for `IEquatable<T>` or `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` implementation (defaulting to `EqualityComparer<T>` if types coincide).

Name selection can be simplified:

```
x.Object1Property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName
    ?? x.Object1Property.Name;
```

Why don't you move it into a separate method `string GetPropertyDisplayName(PropertyInfo)`?

Here you do not need `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Very thorough and your assumptions are largely correct. IComparer is just an interface to restrict usage of the method and to add any additional functions that may intertwine in the future with the compare function, though I will rename it to be more adept. Have some refactoring to do now thank you .

Answer (score 1):

One more tip:

---

> ```
> (Object1Property, Object2Property) => new { Object1Property = Object1Property, Object2Property = Object2Property })
> ```

Here you don't need to repeat the property names. C# can create them implicitly if their names can/should be the same. This means you can just write:

```
(Object1Property, Object2Property) => new { Object1Property, Object2Property })
```